# How to redraw with less alpha

Tags: android, android-custom-view, alpha, invalidation

In my custom View, I'm drawing a rectangle with an alpha of 0. I want that when the user clicks a button, the alpha would change to 100 and redraw. When the mouse button is depressed, alpha should reset to 0. From what I can see, it is not redrawn as 0, but rather on every click it adds 100 without ever going to 0.

```
if(transparentRightClick){
            gameBasePaint.setAlpha(0);
        }
        else{
            gameBasePaint.setAlpha(clickRightColor);
        }
        nextClicked = new RectF(displayWidth*0.8f,displayWidth*0.91f,displayWidth*1f,displayWidth*1.35f);
        gameBaseCanvas.drawRect(nextClicked,gameBasePaint);
```

This is in the 'onDraw' method. When he clicks the button, the 'if'statement is set to false and 'clickRightColor' changes dynamically (0-100) to give an animation effect. When the mouse button is depressed, the 'if' is set to true again, and it should be redrawn to nothing. Calling invalidate after every action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem turned out to be that the 'gameBaseCanvas' wasn't being reinitialized in the onDraw method so it kept on adding to it and never removing the previous drawings.